# Windows 10: Start PXE over ipv4 error

Tags: windows-10, boot, pxe

I've had This problem when that I have seen a lot of answers to on the internet but none of the worked for me.

When I boot I get a black screen that says like initialisation complete or something like that. And at the end it says: **"Start PXE over ipv4"**.
 After a little while, maybe 20 - 30 seconds the computer boots like normal.

I got an msi computer, that might be inportant to know. I got this after i have re-installed windows and I had to mess about in the BIOS to get the windows 10 DVD to boot before everything else and I probably broke something.

So how can i fix this **"Start PXE over ipv4"** error?

Comment: Have you tired to simply disable PXE booting in the firmware?  You should verify that you are not actually using PXE booting, before you do this, disabling it when its actually needed will result in you having to enable it again in order to boot into Windows.  If you are not a system administrator on this computer, you should NOT, disable PXE booting without talking to your administrator first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go back into your BIOS settings and change your boot order to boot from the hard disk before the network adapter.